# Перебор массива с помощью функции array_fill()

Tags: php

Есть цикл перебора массива

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $this->callUp[$i] = 0;
 }
```

где `callUp = []` - изначально пустой массив

Как переписать данное действие с помощью функции `array_fill()` ?

Comment: По PHP есть [очень хороший официальный сайт](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-fill.php) с описанием на многих языках и примерами, а также комментариями пользователей со своими примерами. Настоятельно рекомендую обращаться именно туда в первую очередь.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо так?

```
 $this->callUp = array_fill(0, 10, 0);
```

Comment: сейчас попробую, спасибо !

Answer (score 0):

нужно сначала задать индексы массиву, а потом заполнять его значениями, т.е. $callUp = array_fill(0, 10, 0)